# Joins from 2 separate databases with identical designs

Tags: php, mysql

If I have 2 databases both with completely identical designs but only different data, is there a way to extract a result mimicking that of a single db query such as the use of `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`?

I don't have any specific table design in mind but the project I'm working on already uses multiple dbs. I'm trying to discern which approach works best in cases like these.

Comment: `select * from db1.a union all select * from db2.a`

Comment: One cannot help but wonder how you ended up with multiple databases with identical designs.  Perhaps your application is multihomed and you want to allow for possible forks/customisations?  In which case, you cannot rely on the databases to always be identical and a simple `UNION` may fail (in the future).  It may be better to address this problem in some other way.